# Weird Wordpress 3.5 issue with WYSIWYG

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

Since upgrading to WP 3.5, I'm getting this weird duplication of the WYSIWYG editor:

[image: WYSIWYG duplicated]

For some reason, only refreshing the page sorts the problem - is this an official bug? I've tried disabling all my plugins and it's the same thing....

Thanks,

Osu

Comment: Have you also tried switching themes?

Comment: Hi @janw - yes, I have but no change unfortunately. But that wouldn't affect the admin post editor would it? Thought it might be something to do with my functions.php file, but doesn't seem like that either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the the [3.5 zip](http://wordpress.org/latest.zip).
**Make an update first**
And replace the `wp-admin` folder with a new one.
If that doesn't work try the same with `wp-includes`.

Hopes it helps

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding @janw, Christmas holidays kicked in! Replacing the wp-admin folder sorted it. Thanks